# Can't interact with a turtle after turned into a gif

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically when i turn a turtle into a gif, I can no longer click on it to activate a definiton. It works when the shape isnt a gif, but not when its set to a gif. In this case the gif is named "peashooter".
Here's my code:

```
from turtle import *

t1 = Turtle()
t1.speed(0)
t1.up()
t1.goto(-100, 0)
t1.shape("square")

addshape("peashooter.gif")
shape("square")

def c(x, y):
    print("c")

var = 1

def turn(x, y):
    global var
    
    if var == 1:
        shape("peashooter.gif")
        var = 2
    elif var == 2:
        shape("square")
        var = 1

onclick(c)
t1.onclick(turn)
```

I have absolutely no idea why this isnt working, but I want to be able to have something happen after I've clicked the turtle when its turned into a gif.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out of what to do, the trick was that I had to put onclick in the definition like this:

```
def turn(x, y):
    global var
    
    if var == 1:
        shape("peashooter.gif")
        var = 2
        onclick(c)
    elif var == 2:
        shape("square")
        var = 1
        onclick(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not that well versed withing turtle so dont hate at me for being wrong but I do think I have a solution where you just need change

```
addshape("peashooter.gif")
```

to

```
t1.addshape("peashooter.gif")
```

(NOT ANSWER)

Comment: This doesnt work because addshape isnt a turtle function, but rather a screen function. Thanks for trying either way.

Comment: You should not provide an answer if you do not know that it is an answer.